# weblogic 10.3.5 throwing nullPointerException

Tags: java, struts2, weblogic-10.x

Deployed my struts2 application on weblogic 10.3.5 but it throws a nullPointerException with following trace:

```
> WatchRuleType: Log  WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID =
> 'WL-101020') OR (MSGID = 'WL-101017') OR (MSGID = 'WL-000802') OR
> (MSGID = 'BEA-101020') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101017') OR (MSGID =
> 'BEA-000802'))  WatchData: DATE = Jun 24, 2014 9:58:11 AM EDT SERVER =
> eSrvcs_ManagedServer_1 MESSAGE =
> [ServletContext@1412211888[app:eServices module:eServices.war
> path:/eServices spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:611)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:655)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:914)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
>   at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
>   at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
>   at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
>   at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
> oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
>   at
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
>   at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)  at
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

it appears as if the NPE is thrown by weblogic class and not by struts2 class. As an advice from the guys at apache i set the `archived-real-path` as follows in weblogic.xml.

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
            <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>     
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

However, this does not seem to help with the exception i'm getting. Not sure if this is a bug within the weblogic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after long haul, the problem was JPA 2.0 being not enabled on the server.